# String Regular Expressions - includes and endsWith

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write some regular expressions that simulate the `includes` and `endsWith` functions in JavaScript. I have a string ("ted"). I want to see if that string is included or at the end of any of my other strings using regular expressions.

I saw some examples with a `\b` which, I've never seen before. This made me wonder if there have been some enhancements to RegEx that I haven't been able to find any info about.

Comment: `/ted/` and `/ted$/` and `Array.prototype.some`?

Comment: I wish people would add comments when they downvote. Basically, show what you've tried so far and people are more willing to help rather than just write code for you.

Comment: Yea, more information needed, what do you mean by "other strings"? Couldn´t you just search the other strings one by one through a loop using the "ted" string? In that case, I think you want the \g regex in the end of the expression(g stands for global), it will search the entire string for all occurrences in the string you are searching

Comment: It is hard for us to tell you about regex metacharacters that **you** don't know about. Showing us what you currently have will help us to help you.

Comment: Go to www.regular-expression.info for information about modern regular expressions. But what you're doing doesn't require anything fancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Description

```regex
(?:(?=(?:(for)$)?)(for))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

<sub>** To see the image better, simply right click the image and select view in new window</sub>

This regular expression will do the following:

- simulate the includes and endswith functions
- if the string includes the substring `for` then capture group 2 will be populated.
- if the string ends with `for` then the capture group 1 will be populated.

Notes:

- In Javascript you can run the match then use the .index property of the match to return the character position of the match.
- This being regex, the substring `for` will also match if the substring is located inside other words like `before`, but this seems to be out of scope of this current question.

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/bO5vO3/1

**Sample text**

```
Are these the droids for we for are looking for? These are not the droids you are looking for

Match:               ^1^    ^2^             ^3^                                           ^4^
```

<sub>The second line showing the positions was manually inserted here for illustration purposes, and should not be considered part of the actual sample text.</sub>

**Sample Matches**

```
MATCH 1
2.  `for`

MATCH 2
2.  `for`

MATCH 3
2.  `for`

MATCH 4
1.  `for`
2.  `for`
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\$]                     any character of: '\$'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  this-translate           'this-translate'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [(]                      any character of: '('
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^'\\]                   any character except: ''', '\\'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \\                       '\'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ''                       '\'\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [)]                      any character of: ')'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ;                        ';'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```